# call androidplot library from another apps

Tags: androidplot

i'm developing an android apps to determine the velocity profile. the output which is the velocity profile will be displayed in graphical view using the line chart. x-axis of the graph would be diameter and on the y-axis is the velocity profile. i want to assign the value of diameter and velocity profile to Androidplot.can this apps(Androidplot) be used in my application to display the output in term of line chart? if yes, how can i do it? and do i have to create another layout just to display the graph? or i just display it using the same layout?

This is the visual example that i try to accomplish:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly35A.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since Androidplot is a library the only way to use it is to include it in your app - so yes :-)  For Gradle projects, it's as simple as adding this to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.androidplot:androidplot-core:0.9.3"
}
```

Once that's in, you can insert the Plot anywhere any other Android View can be inserted; Fragments, Activities, Widgets, etc.  There's no need to have a separate layout either.  As far as how to get started - the best place to begin is the [Quickstart example](http://androidplot.com/docs/quickstart/).

As far as styling the plot to look like the visual example you provided - not familiar with that sort of visualization but it doesn't really look like an XY graph to me.